# Pins not showing up in Chrome Google Maps Api V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

For some reason my pins aren't showing in the chrome browser. They do in safari, opera, firefox etc etc but not in chrome.

I get an undefined typeerror in the google api lib, so can't do anything with it.

This is my code where i add my google map:

```
var map;
function loadStores(){

google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
if(typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object'){
    try{
        var mapoptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.492537, -99.901813),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            panControl: false
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("store_map"),
        mapoptions);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

        addStores();
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
}
```

This is my code to add the stores(pins) to the map:

```
if(typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object'){
    try{
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: api_url + '/locations',
            success: function(data){
                var stores = $.parseJSON(data);

                for(var i=0; i<stores.length; i++){
                    console.log("hallo");
                    var ii = i;
                    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/store/pin_@2x.png', null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(32,50));
                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(stores[ii].latitude, stores[ii].longitude);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatLng,
                        map:map,
                        icon: image,
                        tel: stores[ii].tel,
                        state: stores[ii].state,
                        street: stores[ii].street
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                        opPinGeklikt(event, this);
                    });
                }

            },error:function(){
                console.log(arguments);
            }
        });

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Any toughts would be great.

Comment: set your dataType to "json" and remove $.parseJSON(). Are you absolutely sure the typeerror is from inside the maps api, and not your code? Also, i don't see where `map` is defined, but that shouldn't be *the* issue if it's working in other browsers.

Comment: Changed it to json, doesn't affect anything. map is defined in another function, so that's no issue. This is the error i get: http://d.pr/i/q3A2 and the main.js is the google api js file..

Comment: Found out that my map freezes when i zoom out, also only in chrome.

Comment: What is the last thing in your code that is reached before the error occurs? you should be able to trace that from the error.

Comment: The error appears to happen on my marker.

Comment: In that case, compare the values returned from your json request between firefox and chrome.

Comment: Data is perfectly the same, really getting desperate here. I've worked for many times with the google maps API, and this is (almost) an exact copy paste of what i used to work with. And the fact that it's working perfect in safari, ff and so on and not in chrome is just not possible to understand.

Comment: Ok found it. I tested it on some other laptops on Chrome OS and it works like a charm. I reïnstalled (updated?) my chrome OS and seems like that did the trick. Pretty stupid, but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it. I tested it on some other laptops on Chrome OS and it works like a charm. I reïnstalled (updated?) my chrome OS and seems like that did the trick. Pretty stupid, but it worked.